# Aurelia application startup issue in contact manager tutorial

Tags: webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap, aurelia

I am working through the contact manager tutorial and when I get to the addition of the router my app stops working. Any hints would be appreciated. It appears to be a problem loading bootstrap.css. This is the output from the Chrome debug window:

```
DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-binding. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-binding. vendor-bundle.js:13902 

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-resources. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-resources. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-event-aggregator. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-event-aggregator. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-history-browser. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-history-browser. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-router. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-router. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin resources/index. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin resources/index. vendor-bundle.js:13902 

DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-testing. vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-testing. vendor-bundle.js:13902 

DEBUG [templating] importing resources for aurelia-templating-resources/compose [] vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [templating] importing resources for aurelia-templating-router/router-view [] vendor-bundle.js:13912

INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started vendor-bundle.js:13902

DEBUG [templating] importing resources for app.html ["bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css", "styles.css"] vendor-bundle.js:4834

Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function

at Module.<anonymous> (vendor-bundle.js:4834)

at vendor-bundle.js:3873

at on (vendor-bundle.js:4256)

at Module.callPlugin (vendor-bundle.js:4694)

at Module.fetch (vendor-bundle.js:4563)

at Module.check (vendor-bundle.js:4595)

at Module.enable (vendor-bundle.js:4915)

at Object.enable (vendor-bundle.js:5296)

at Module.<anonymous> (vendor-bundle.js:4900)

at vendor-bundle.js:3873

at each (vendor-bundle.js:3798)

at Module.enable (vendor-bundle.js:4852)

at Module.init (vendor-bundle.js:4527)

at vendor-bundle.js:5199
```

Answer (score 2):

Most often you will get this error when:

- you are trying to load a css file or another text based file (like svg)
- this css file / other text based file is not included in the bundle
- the [stub](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-cli-ion-rangeslider/blob/master/aurelia_project/aurelia.json#L74) property is set to `true`

You could do one of two things, include the css file in the bundle or set the [stub](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-cli-ion-rangeslider/blob/master/aurelia_project/aurelia.json#L74) property to `false`.

I recommend the former, which means that in aurelia.json you configure a `resources` property:

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
  "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
  "deps": ["jquery"],
  "exports": "$",
  "resources": [
    "css/bootstrap.css"
  ]
}
```

This should trigger the CLI to bundle the `bootstrap.css` file. If you set the `stub` property to `false` then RequireJS will fetch the bootstrap.css file outside of the bundle (so a separate request will happen).

Comment: I already had the bootstrap reference in aurelia.json. I went to try setting the stub property, first adding the require line back in to app.html. On saving the ts the app now loads correctly. I did build out the rest of the app following the tutorial so that change also. I am going to reproduce this and see what step makes it work.